# mapStateToProps called but not calling componentWillRecieveProps when state has same value

Tags: react-native, react-redux, state, react-props

I have the following reducer:

```
export default function UserReducer(state = initialState, action){
let nextState;
switch(action.type){
    case USER_RECOVERY_CODE_VALIDATED:
    nextState = {
        ...state,
        recoverycodevalidated : action.payload.recoverycodevalidated
    }
    return nextState;
default:
     return state;
 }
}
```

And my component is connected to the store that way:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    console.log("updated");
    return { recoverycodevalidated: state.user.recoverycodevalidated };
 }

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ResetPasswordCodeScreen)
```

And when the props change thanks to the ***mapStateToProps*** function, I redirect the user to the next screen:

```
 async componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
    console.log("updated props");
    if(newProps.recoverycodevalidated){
        this.props.navigation.navigate("ResetPasswordFinal", { userId: this.props.navigation.state.params.userId});
    }
}
```

The problem is that when the state is updated the first time and the value of ***recoverycodevalidated*** is set in the props, the second time if the value of the variable is the same, the props are not updated because the method ***componentWillRecieveProps*** is not fired, eventhough the ***mapStateToProps*** is fired everytime. What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Neither your componentWillReceiveProps nor your component will be updated ... as long as the value for `recoverycodevalidated` you received in your mapStateToProps is  the same

Answer (score 0):

Try using **componentDidUpdate** instead

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) { 
     console.log("updated props");
     if (prevProps.recoverycodevalidated) {
        this.props.navigation.navigate("ResetPasswordFinal", { userId: 
        this.props.navigation.state.params.userId});
     }
}
```